# Avoid transaction when reading data through a linked server

Tags: sql-server, etl

This is SQL Server related.

**Is there other techniques that I can use for this?** (Read data from a procedure in another server.)

I'm trying to re-use a stored procedure from another sever instance through a linked server. The stored procedure selects a few columns and rows (single, small resultset). Let's say this procedure resides on "Sever A".

I'm able to run the procedure from "Server B" and get the data, however, I also need to join the retrieved data against local tables.

I tried

```
insert into @LocalTableVariable exec [LinkedServer].[remotebase].[dbo].[procedure]
```

but that generates the following error:

> The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider
>   "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SERVER_A" was unable to begin a
>   distributed transaction.

The linked served has RPC enabled and promote transactions enabled.

Also tried with table valued functions, but in this form:

```
select * from [SERVER_A].Database.dbo.table_function(parameter_1)
```

Produced the error:

> Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed.

At the end I was able to perform the insert by using **Dynamic SQL** combined with **openquery**, but I really want to avoid Dynamic SQL to diminish SQL injection and the maintenance difficulties related to double and quadruple quoting. quad-quotes ara almos always necessary as parameters must be passed to the remote procedure or function. For Openquery does not accept variables, in order to make use of it, a second "layer" is added with exec sp_executesql.

Here is an example of what I do to read data from table functions.

```
set @sentence = concat('select * from Openquery([SERVER_A], ''Select Col_1, Col_2, ... Col_n Database.dbo.table_function(''''',@parameter_1,''''', ''''',@parameter_2,''''', ''''',@parameter_3,''''')'')')

insert into @tableVariable ... exec sp_executesql @sentence
```

Here is another way of doing it, this time shown with a procedure call:

```
set @sentence = concat('exec Database.dbo.stored_procedure ''',@parameter_1,''', ''',@parameter_2,'''')

set @sentence = concat('select * from Openquery([SERVER_A], ''',replace(@sentence , '''', ''''''),''')') -- With this at least I reduce the risk of miscounting quad quotes.

insert into @table_variable (...) exec sp_executesql @sentence
```

*Edit*: Also tried the pattern proposed by Aaron:

```
declare @param_1 varchar(10) = '...', @param_2 varchar(1) = '.'
        declare @sentence nvarchar(4000) = concat('exec Database.dbo.stored_procedure''',@param_1,''', ''',@param_2,''';')

        insert into @table_variable (...) exec [SERVER_A].Database.sys.sp_executesql @sentence;
```

That resulted in the same error I mentioned before.

For the tasks related to the same project I also tried table valued functions, but those also failed with an error, and where only usable (remotely) by means of Dynamic SQL.

I cannot use a view in "Server A" because there is additional logic needed prior to selecting the final result set. This logic is what I want to encapsulate as it is needed in both servers

Comment: Dynamic SQL <> SQL injection. Can you show the dynamic SQL you ended up with? How complex is your procedure call that you need to worry about double and quadruple quotes? Have you tried `insert #localtemp exec linkedserver.remotebase.sys.sp_executesql N'EXEC dbo.procedure;';`?

Comment: Set 'remote proc transaction promotion' to false if you don't need a distributed transaction. You could create another linked server with that option set to false if you have other queries that use the existing linked server and need it set to true.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Dynamic SQL opens a door that may enable an SQL Injection attack. Some of the procedures I have to support are text searches where the terms are user input. I'm not posting code as my question is more oriented to find a technique I'm not yet aware of. The complexity of the query will depend on the particular procedure, and I have several.

Comment: Driving a car opens a door that may enable a car accident. You can take steps to reduce the risk, but most people don't find it acceptable (never mind necessary) to shun cars entirely. There are many ways you can protect yourself from SQL injection (see [part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/) and [part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/) to see that I'm not just hand-waving), but there are some things dynamic SQL can solve that nothing else can.